# File input and Output Serialization

Tags: serialization

I just want someone to comment on this code for me to understand what the code is doing, it is perfect but i dont understand. I know this site has professional coders and so far i dont know how to debug.

please just by commenting it out make me understand step by step what it does.

```
import java.io.EOFException;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Serialization {
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException,ClassNotFoundException {
    File file = new File("students.txt");
    ArrayList<Student> psy101 = new ArrayList<Student>();

    psy101.add (new Student("Bob", 2.9));
    psy101.add(new Student("Smith", 3.9));
    psy101.add(new Student("John",4.9));
    psy101.add(new Student("Amy",10.9));


    FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(file);
    ObjectOutputStream output = new ObjectOutputStream(fo);

    for(Student s : psy101){
    output.writeObject(s);


}
output.close();
fo.close();


FileInputStream fi = new FileInputStream(file);
ObjectInputStream input = new ObjectInputStream(fi);
ArrayList<Student> psy1012 = new ArrayList<Student>();
try{
while (true){
    Student s = (Student)input.readObject();
     psy1012.add(s);
}
}catch (EOFException ex){

}
for (Student s : psy1012){
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

and the other class is this one, any kind of comment will be appreciated.

```
import java.io.Serializable;

public class Student implements Serializable {
private String Name;
private double GPA;

public Student(String name, double gpa){
    this.Name = name;
    this.GPA = gpa;

}

public String getName() {
    return this.Name;
}

public String getName(String newName) {
    return(this.Name = newName);
}

public double getGPA() {
    return this.GPA;
}

public double setGPA(double newgGPA) {
    return (this.GPA = GPA);
}
@Override
    public String toString() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return String.format("%s\t%f",this.Name,this.GPA);
    }
}
```

Comment: What IDE are you using? Most have debuggers where you can see everything happening perfectly

Comment: I use Eclipse and actually i dont know how to debug, that is my biggest worry and there are no videos online on debugging.

Comment: Or would you suggest to me how someone should debug? maybe that will help me out.

Comment: Of course there are videos. Here's one: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9gAjIQc4bPU The suggestions next to it should list you some others as well.

Comment: What 9n earth are these mutating accessors? Don't write code like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First i can see that you have two classes,

the first class for serialization and the second is for the student.
Now i can not comment line to line but i will offer some info, so that you can read more on the same.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/

Writing to a Text File

To write text to a file you open an output stream by using the class FileWriter. If the file does not exist a new empty file with this name is created. If the file already exists opening it erases the data in the file. If you want to append to the file use the following option when creating the FileWriter object:

FileWriter fWriter = new FileWriter (outFile, true);
The class PrintWriter has methods print(), printf() and println() that will allow us to write to a file.

This will also help you.
http://www.cs.utexas.edu/~mitra/csSummer2009/cs303/lectures/fileIO.html

Now i believe once you run your code you will notice that the students.txt will have the info in your code and console, however it will be serialized,Java provides a mechanism, called object serialization where an object can be represented as a sequence of bytes that includes the object's data as well as information about the object's type and the types of data stored in the object.

After a serialized object has been written into a file, it can be read from the file and deserialized that is, the type information and bytes that represent the object and its data can be used to recreate the object in memory.

Most impressive is that the entire process is JVM independent, meaning an object can be serialized on one platform and deserialized on an entirely different platform . So read more on the above and it should help.

Comment: importantly use the video given above.